# Importance of original features after applying PCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, pca

Assume that I have 5 features A, B, C, D, E.

I apply PCA to my data to reduce the dimensionality to 3. It means now I have 3 principal components where each PC is a new variable. Now I want to know which feature among A, B, C, D, E is most important, which is the 2nd most important feature and so on and by how much (such as in terms of score).

I know that the first PC has the highest variance(importance), followed by 2nd, followed by 3rd and so on but I want the importance among original features A, B, C, D, E. Is there any method to find it?

Comment: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/randomforest2001.pdf

Answer (score 2):

`PCA` ranking criteria is the variance of each columns, if you would like to have a ranking, what you can do is to output the `VarianceThreshold` of each columns. You can do that by this

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

selector = VarianceThreshold()
selector.fit_transform(dataframe)
print(selector.variances_)
```